# WhatsApp outbound message

Tags: marketing-cloud, whatsapp

It is required to have different ids in marketing cloud whatsapp for advertising and informational outbound message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.